# Problems with "onload" and XHTML Validation

Tags: php, javascript, xhtml, onload, w3c-validation

My name is Manuel, I am a web design student and am starting to take my first steps with web design. Recently I tried to validate

this site:

http://accesosnormalizados.com

I used the W3C validator, at first I found about 30 errors, and can correct them all except one that says: 'there is no attribute

"onload"'.

Apparently not support XHTML onload tag, and I use a Joomla extension called Vertical Menu using onload. This is a free extension and works well but I have found it has some bugs, especially when validating the website.

This is the PHP code for extension:

```
    get( 'menutype', 'mainmenu' );
    $qry = "SELECT id, name,parent, link,type,browserNav FROM #__menu WHERE menutype = '".$menutype."' AND published = 1 ORDER BY ordering";
    $database->setQuery($qry);
    $rows = $database->loadObjectList();

    if(isset($GLOBALS['vertical_menu'])) $GLOBALS['vertical_menu']++;
    else $GLOBALS['vertical_menu'] = 0;

        function getMenuChildList($rows, $parentId) {
            $childRows = array();
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                if ($row->parent == $parentId) {
                    $childRows[] = $row;
                }
            }
            return $childRows;
        }

        function drawVerticalMenu($rows, $showsubcats, $parentId = 0) {
            $categories = $showsubcats || !$parentId ? getMenuChildList($rows, $parentId) : array();
            if ($parentId) {
                if (!count($categories)) {
                    echo '';
                    return;
                } else echo '';
                echo '';
            } else echo '';
            echo '';
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $link = $category->link. (preg_match("/^http:\/\/|^https:\/\//",$category->link)? "" : '&Itemid='.$category->id);
                $blank = $category->browserNav? ' target="_blank" ' : ' ';
                echo 'id.'" class="menu">'.$category->name.' ';
                drawVerticalMenu($rows, $showsubcats, $category->id);
            }
            echo '';
            if ($parentId && count($categories)) echo '';
        }

    $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js');
    $document->addScript('modules/mod_vertical_menu/script/menu.js');
    $document->addStyleSheet('modules/mod_vertical_menu/style/menu.css');
    $document->addCustomTag('
    
    div#MenuContainer'.$GLOBALS['vertical_menu'].' table#VerticalMenu'.$GLOBALS['vertical_menu'].' {
        width: '.$params->get('categorymenu_width', 150).'px;
        opacity: '.$params->get('categorymenu_out', 0.8).';
        FILTER:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity='.($params->get('categorymenu_out', 0.8)*100).');
    }
    
    ');
    echo '';
    drawVerticalMenu($rows, $params->get('show_subcats', 1));

    echo 'get('categorymenu_out', 0.8).',over : '.$params->get('categorymenu_over', 1).',duration : '.$params->get('categorymenu_fade', 300).',id : '.$GLOBALS['vertical_menu'].',width : '.$params->get('categorymenu_width', 150).'});" alt=""/>';
    echo '';

    ?>
```

The problem is at the end:

```
    echo '';
    drawVerticalMenu($rows, $params->get('show_subcats', 1));

    echo 'get('categorymenu_out', 0.8).',over : '.$params->get('categorymenu_over', 1).',duration : '.$params->get('categorymenu_fade', 300).',id : '.$GLOBALS['vertical_menu'].',width : '.$params->get('categorymenu_width', 150).'});" alt=""/>';
    echo '';

    ?>
```

I think the extension uses the onload event to display the sub-menus when the user moves the mouse pointer over it.

What I want is to replace the onload with other event handler or some other label that is supported by XHTML and that is as similar to onload.

I would appreciate your help ...

Comment: your question seems to confuse onload the javascript event that is fired on pageload and mouse hover? Add the HTML output for more clarity

Comment: @Shaun Hare: it's the onload-event of an img

Comment: This is the error that the W3C Validator gives me when I try to validate the page. 

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Faccesosnormalizados.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Click on the link and you will see the error right on line 224. There you will see what the HTML output and where the problem is.

Comment: my apologies i did not follow the link

Comment: I don't see the onload attribute ... ?  Can you post the actual XHTML tag that is causing the error instead of the rest of the code (that seems irrelevant to the problem).

Comment: xhtml does not support onload for images, it does however support it on other tags

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem. But that piece of code is generated by a  Joomla extension called VerticalMenu. So I know XHTML does not support onload in the <img> and I want to change that piece of code for other one that supported by xhtml.

Then I let the piece of PHP code that generates line 224.

Comment: echo '<div id="MenuContainer'.$GLOBALS['vertical_menu'].'">';
drawVerticalMenu($rows, $params->get('show_subcats', 1));

echo '<img src="modules/mod_vertical_menu/images/center.gif" style="display:none" onload="new WW.VerticalMenu({out : '.$params->get('categorymenu_out', 0.8).',over : '.$params->get('categorymenu_over', 1).',duration : '.$params->get('categorymenu_fade', 300).',id : '.$GLOBALS['vertical_menu'].',width : '.$params->get('categorymenu_width', 150).'});" alt=""/>';
echo '</div>';

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the onload attributes and then add some simple javaScript to your page to run some functions when the page finishes loading.

It would look something like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
       new WW.VerticalMenu({out : 1,over : 1,duration : 300,id : 0,width : 180}); // example of one of the functions being run
    };
</script>
```

Good luck with your studies

Comment: Hi pzirkind,

Thank you very much for your help. I could fix the problem using the script you recommended me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the source comes out like this right

```
<img src="/modules/mod_vertical_menu/images/center.gif" style="display:none" onload="new WW.VerticalMenu({out : 1,over : 1,duration : 300,id : 0,width : 180});" alt=""/>
```

As that looks like imho an unsavoury method of instantiating the menu I would try and loose that attribute completely by removing the offending php echo section and instead add javascript to load 
as this is using dojo maybe this will help -- sorry I do not use dojo 
http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2012-May/066106.html

so php wise this would be

```
echo '<img src="modules/mod_vertical_menu/images/center.gif" style="display:none"  alt=""/>'; echo '</div>'; 

 echo "<script>" ."javascript or dojo script here ".</script>"
```

I would even suggest removing the image and using the window onload advocated below if you can